# Rbind: Add name of source as column and/or variable in the new combined dataset

Tags: r, plyr, rbind

I'm using Rbind to combine multiple datasets into one big dataframe.

For future reference, I want to be able to see from which dataset a row originates from.

Is there an easy way to do this without using the ID's or other 'hacks'?

Example of source files:

```
Sales_East <- (read.csv('salesEast.csv')
Sales_West<- (read.csv('salesWest.csv')
Dataset <- rbind.fill(Sales_East,Sales_West)
```

The resulting dataset:

```
ID Order Amount 
1  2     10
2  1     5
A  4     20
B  2     10
```

But I'm looking for something more like this:

```
ID Order Amount Source 
1  2     10     East
2  1     5      East
A  4     20     West
B  2     10     West
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's only a couple dataframes you want to row-bind, just add the source yourself:

```
Sales_East <- read.csv('salesEast.csv')
Sales_East$Source <- "East"

Sales_West <- read.csv('salesWest.csv')
Sales_West$Source <- "West"

Dataset <- rbind.fill(Sales_East, Sales_West)
```

If you have a whole bunch of dataframes, you need to get their names in a character vector by either writing it yourself or using `ls()`.  But once you have it, you can do this:

```
dfnames <- c("Sales_East", "Sales_West")
do.call(rbind, lapply(dfnames, function(x) cbind(get(x), Source=x)))
```

Comment: Fair enough, that'll work! Thanks @Dan. I do however feel like there should be a more 'natural' connection between the two (source & row).

Comment: I agree that it would be a nice option to have as, say, an arg to rowbind.